# Generating anchor points using table in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gps

I have geocoded multiple points based on GPS data over 7 days. Each point has a duration, speed (see table and arcmap image). I would like to create anchor points from this file, that is merge all points that are stationary in the same location, across all points e.g. Home as anchor (which have geocoded in another file), shops, school etc.

Could anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

I would like to also measure the frequency of trips to the same destination and the durations of these trips.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is it correct that you have points in a feature class and some of them overlap each other, i.e., they have the same coordinates? Now, you want to find a group of points that share the same coordinates and then unite them into a single point. How the source points attributes should be handled? Also, what exactly do you mean by `anchor points`? If you could draw a simple picture with a sample of data that you have and the result you wish to get, I think it will be easier to comprehend.

Comment: Try tool Integrate: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. To try and explain: I use the term anchor points to describe the land use that the user frequents and stops at (e.g. shops might be an anchor point, park might be another key anchor point, school another). I basically have numerous points that are mapped and have a time/distance component which I am trying to unpick to show where people are stationary (anchor point) for large chunks of time, rather than just "driving" through as it were. For example 10 points might condense down to one point if the speed is less that 5 kms per hour for a certain period of time an